# Exposing Azure Arc identity endpoint to docker container

Tags: .net, linux, azure, docker, docker-swarm

I have Azure Arc installed on all the nodes of our docker swarm. I want to use their managed identities to access Azure resources. Querying an access token from the host machine works fine, but I am struggling to get the same access from inside a container.

I tried `extra_host`, port mapping, etc, but I keep getting connection refused/failed to connect errors. The `host` network mode option would probably work, but is unavailable in docker swarm. I also can't find any documentation on changing the Azure Arc endpoint binding from `127.0.0.1` to a different network interface.

What I basically have at this point:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    ports:
      - '5127:8080'
      - '40342:40342'
    environment:
      - 'IMDS_ENDPOINT=http://127.0.0.1:40342'
      - 'IDENTITY_ENDPOINT=http://127.0.0.1:40342/metadata/identity/oauth2/token'
```

How do give the docker container access to the identity endpoint, so that my ASP.NET server can authenticate itself in azure?

[image: Setup diagram]

Comment: To give the Docker container access to azcmagent, you need to expose the agent's endpoint to the container. According to the Azure Arc-enabled Kubernetes agent overview, the Azure Arc agents require outbound communication to a set list of network endpoints. Therefore, you can configure the Docker container to allow outbound communication to the required endpoints. You can also use the host network mode option,but if you want to avoid that, you can try the following steps:

Comment: Determine the IP address of the host machine running the azcmagent. You can use the command ip addr show to list the IP addresses of the host machine.
Expose the endpoint of the azcmagent to the Docker container by adding the IP address and port of the azcmagent to the Docker container's environment variables or configuration files. For example, you can add the following environment variable to the Docker container:
   `-e AZURE_ARC_AGENT_ENDPOINT=http://<ip-address-of-host-machine>:30080`
This assumes that the azcmagent is listening on port 30080 on host machine.Adjust port based on config

Comment: According to the Private connectivity for Arc-enabled Kubernetes clusters using private link documentation, you need to allow outbound TCP 443 (HTTPS) access to Microsoft Entra ID, Azure Resource Manager, Azure Front Door, and Microsoft Container Registry. You can configure the Docker container's network security group (NSG) to allow outbound traffic to these endpoints using the az network nsg rule create command.

Comment: For example, you can create a rule to allow outbound traffic to Microsoft Container Registry using the following command: `az network nsg rule create --resource-group <resource-group-name> --nsg-name <nsg-name> --name AllowMCROutboundAccess --priority 153 --source-address-prefixes '*' --destination-address-prefixes 'MicrosoftContainerRegistry' --destination-port-ranges '443' --access Allow --protocol Tcp` Replace <resource-group-name> and <nsg-name> with the name of the resource group and NSG associated with the Docker container's subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Arc-enabled servers expose the [IMDS (Azure Instance Metadata Service) endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/servers/managed-identity-authentication#security-overview) on the local host of the physical server. That endpoint is inaccessible from within a Docker container by default because the container is isolated from the host network.

Since you cannot directly alter the binding of the Azure Arc endpoint, you could try and run a proxy server on the host that forwards requests to the IMDS endpoint. Docker containers can then be configured to communicate with this proxy instead of directly with the IMDS endpoint.

```
events { }
http {
    server {
        listen 40345;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:40342;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

You would then run `nginx` on the host, outside of Docker, but listening on a network interface that is accessible to Docker containers.

In your Docker Compose file, you need to set the environment variables to point to the host proxy instead of the localhost. You also need to mount `/var/opt/azcmagent` because ASP.NET will try to store tokens in that directory.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    ports:
      - '5127:8080'
    environment:
      - 'IMDS_ENDPOINT=http://host.docker.internal:80'
      - 'IDENTITY_ENDPOINT=http://host.docker.internal:80/metadata/identity/oauth2/token'
    extra_hosts:
      - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
    volumes:
      - '/var/opt/azcmagent:/var/opt/azcmagent'
```

With these changes, your ASP.NET server within the Docker container should be able to access the Azure Arc identity endpoint via the host proxy.

Comment: Reverse proxy is indeed the way to go! I did update your answer with some missing details that were required to get things working.

Comment: Also, it is possible to run the reverse proxy itself in docker, but you have to make sure that the network mode is set to `host`, and that you are using `docker compose` instead of `docker stack`

Comment: @RickdeWater Great, well done! Thank you for the edit.